# How do I stop each letter from printing on different line?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

When I try to **scrape** some text with beautifulsoup

```
class scrape(object):
    
        def dirae(self, word):
            url = 'http://dirae.es/palabras/' + word
            site = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(site.read())
            for result in soup.select('div.definitionContent')[0].get_text():
                print(result.encode('utf-8'))
    
    search = scrape()
    search.dirae('bellota')
```

Example of the html code:

```
 <div class="definitionContent">
    <li><p>Text</p></li>
    <li><p>Text</p></li>
 </div>
```

I get:

```
T
e
x
t

T
e
x
t
```

I want to get the output on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`soup.select('div.definitionContent')[0].get_text()` is returning a string. So doing a `for` on it means you are iterating in the characters.

You can try do like this:

```
class scrape(object):

    def dirae(self, word):
        url = 'http://dirae.es/palabras/' + word
        site = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(site.read())
        print soup.select('div.definitionContent')[0].get_text().enconde('utf-8')
```

Comment: `for result in soup.select('div.definitionContent'):
....  print(result.get_text().encode('utf-8'))` is better for me